# Java 8. Is it a good or bad practice to pass a method which changes a state of a class as Runnable into another method of this class

Tags: java-8

Just noticed an interesting feature of Java 8. This actually helped me to avoid lots of refactoring but I'm not sure if this is good to do like that.
So dear Stackoverflowers, could you tell me whether this correct or not?

Here is simply what I've done

E.g. there is a service which I want to execute and it should have execution modes

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Service
public class SomeService {

@Value("${com.example.url.mode.1}")
private String runnerURLmode1;

@Value("${com.example.url.mode.2}")
private String runnerURLmode2;

@Value("${example.url.mode.3}")
private String runnerURLmode3;

private String modeDependingField1;
private Integer modeDependingField2;
private LocalDate modeDependingField3;

public void setMode1() {
    modeDependingField1 = runnerURLmode1;
    modeDependingField2 = 1;
    modeDependingField3 = LocalDate.now();
}

public void setMode2() {
    modeDependingField1 = runnerURLmode2;
    modeDependingField2 = 2;
    modeDependingField3 = LocalDate.now().minusDays(2);
}

public void setMode3() {
    modeDependingField1 = runnerURLmode3;
    modeDependingField2 = 3;
    modeDependingField3 = LocalDate.now().minusDays(5);
}

public void execute(Runnable mode) {
    mode.run();

    System.out.println(toString());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "modeDependingField1: " + modeDependingField1 + "\n" +
            "modeDependingField2: " + modeDependingField2 + "\n" +
            "modeDependingField3: " + modeDependingField3;
}
}
```

And a service consumer

```
public class ServiceExecutor {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeService someService = new SomeService();

    System.out.println("========= Executin mode 1 ===========");
    someService.execute(someService::setMode1);

    System.out.println("\n\n========= Executin mode 2 ===========");
    someService.execute(someService::setMode2);

    System.out.println("\n\n========= Executin mode 3 ===========");
    someService.execute(someService::setMode3);

}

}
```

So I get the output:

> ========= Executin mode 1 ===========
>   modeDependingField1: 1
>   modeDependingField2: 1
>   modeDependingField3: 2017-05-03
>
> ========= Executin mode 2 ===========
>   modeDependingField1: 2
>   modeDependingField2: 2
>   modeDependingField3: 2017-05-01
>
> ========= Executin mode 3 =========== 
>   modeDependingField1: 3 
>   modeDependingField2: 3
>   modeDependingField3: 2017-04-28

Comment: maybe you need an enum to describe `mode`, then you can reduce `setMode`s to only one `setMode` method.

Comment: I don't understand the benefit of this. You are still calling 3 methods - but now via a `Runnable` indirection.

Comment: @holi-java, Yep, actually this is the same as if I declare an enum

Comment: @Eugene, the first solution was just declaring of these setters and calling them from consumer before the execute method but if to use the execute method in the future it is required to remember that setMode has to be called. In this case it is not forgetable

Comment: Your `execute` method doesn’t actually do anything, so it’s not clear, why it should be important to it, whether one of the `setMode` methods has been called. In fact, it still can’t ensure that the provided `Runnable` will invoke one of these methods. The logical approach would be to make `execute` `private` and let the `setMode` methods invoke it at the end; that way, it is sure that there is a `setMode` method executed right before `execute`…

Comment: so the only advantage over calling `someService.setMode1(); someService.setMode2(); someService.setMode3(); ` is having the `println(toString())`call?

Comment: Edited a bit the description: I need to use fields from the class in the setters so it is not possible to use enum as it accepts static fields only

Comment: To thouse who asks about execute() - no, it does many actions depending on the mode fields. Obvoiusly I won't post a project code. But please believe me all these fields are in use

Comment: And finally the question is about passing mehod reference as Runnable parameter. As for me this looks very unclear. Is it really fine?